# shuffle elements of two ngFor loops

Tags: angular, ngfor

I've got an Angualar project that uses this code:

```
<app-red-elements *ngFor="let redElement of redElements" [element]="redElement"></app-video>
<app-blue-elements *ngFor="let bluElement of blueElements" [element]="blueElement"></app-video>
```

And displays:

```
1.redElement
2.redElement
3.redElement
1.blueElement
2.blueElement
3.blueElement
```

I want to give the user an option to shuffle elements. Not only red elements between each other and blue elements between each other, but also red and blue elements with each other. For example, this is a valid configuration:

```
1.redElement
2.blueElement
2.redElement
1.blueElement
3.blueElement
3.redElement
```

As far as I know I cannot do this with the HTML above. What solution do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[lodash shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#shuffle)** method to achieve this.

```
<app-red-elements *ngFor="let redElement of getRandom(redElements)" [element]="redElement"></app-video>
<app-blue-elements *ngFor="let bluElement of getRandom(blueElements)" [element]="blueElement"></app-video>
```

Add a component method as below,

```
getRandom(arrayToBeShuffled){
   _.shuffle(arrayToBeShuffled);
}
```

Update based on Chat

To have them shuffled you should have it as a single array as below,

```
<span *ngFor="let element of elements"> 
<app-red-elements *ngIf="element.type === 'Red'" [element]="element.redElement"></app-video> 
<app-blue-elements *ngIf="element.type === 'Blue'" [element]="element.blueElement"></app-video> 
</span>
```

Your `elements`  should have additional property `type` which will look as

```
elements=[
    {type:'Red',redElement:...}
    {type:'Blue',blueElement:...}
]
```

Comment: Would this allow me to place blueElement before redElement? Because it look that it only shuffles one array at a time.

Comment: so where is the value for `redElements` comes from?

Comment: A simple shuffle does: 2.redElement, 1.redElement, 3.redElement, 3.blueElement,1.blueElement,2.blueElement. But that is not what I want. I also want to be able to shuffle red and blue elements with each other.

Comment: these two are separate `arrays` or combined in a single array?

Comment: separate arrays.

Comment: then how can you shuffle them ? is it possible to combine both?

Comment: nope, blue and redElements have some properties in common, but many of them aren't. The only thing that matters is the order at which they are displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161061/discussion-between-aravind-and-sanjihan).

Comment: This helped me..but I had to return the ``arrayToBeShuffled`` from the ``getRandom()`` function. I used this function in my view. ``<li *ngFor="let foo of shuffleAnswers(arrayToBeShuffled))"``

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```js
shufflingArray (value: any[]) {

    let items: any[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      items.push(value[i]);
    }

    // reversing items array
    for (let i = items.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      // console.log([items[i], items[j]]);
      // console.log([items[j], items[i]]);
      [items[i], items[j]] = [items[j], items[i]];
    }
    return items;
}
```